# How to make slideIn AND slideOut with styled-components with react-animations

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, react-animations

I'm working on building a component that displays `none` or `block` depending on it's `isActive` prop.

I've managed to make it `slideInDown` using `react-animations` with `styled-components` like this.

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';
import { ifProp } from 'styled-tools';
import { slideInDown } from 'react-animations';

const slideInAnimation = keyframes`${slideInDown}`;

const MyComponent = styled.div`
  animation: 0.4s ${slideInAnimation};
  display: ${ifProp('isActive', 'block', 'none')};
`;
```

I need to make it `slideOutUp` now. However, I'm not sure how to implement both `slideInDown` and `slideOutUp` animations together.

How would I accomplish that?

**Note:** that works. But I don't know how to make it both slide in and out. I tried something like this below but that didn't work.

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';
import { ifProp } from 'styled-tools';
import { slideInDown, slideOutUp } from 'react-animations';

const slideInAnimation = keyframes`${slideInDown}`;
const slideOutAnimation = keyframes`${slideOutUp}`;

const MyComponent = styled.div`
  animation: 0.4s ${slideInAnimation}, 0.4s ${slideOutAnimation};
  display: ${ifProp('isActive', 'block', 'none')};
`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the `react-animations` library, what I figured out is [slideOutUp](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-animations/blob/master/src/slide-out-up.js) sets `visibility: 'hidden.'`

```
const slideOutUp: Animation = {
  from: {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  },
  to: {
    visibility: 'hidden',
    transform: translate3d(0, '-100%', 0)
  }
};
```

You can use `animation-fill-mode: forwards`, which helps in retaining the style after the animation ends.

You can do something like this (it works):

```
const MyComponent = styled.div`
  animation: ${ifProp(
    "isActive",
    `0.4s ${slideInAnimation}`,
    `0.4s ${slideOutAnimation} forwards`
  )};
`;
```

Here is the working example, for testing purpose `onClick` event I am setting `{isActive: false}`

https://codesandbox.io/s/949ql6p6no

Comment: The animation works, my example was just badly written sorry. I need to make it slide back out again. Don't know how to make stuff slide in AND slide out.

Comment: I  have updated my answer. Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Got bogged down with other stuff. I'll give this a shot in a few days. Thanks man :)

Comment: Haha will do ;) It did help :D

Answer (score 0):

`Display` does not animate. You need to use opacity for toggling (1 to 0 and vice versa) and animation.

```
const myComponent = styled.div`
  animation: 0.4s ${slideInAnimation};
  opacity: ${ifProp('isActive', 1, 0)};
`;
```

Considering that your code is working like you told me, you can use the attribute infinte at animation:

```
animation: 0.4s ${slideInAnimation} infinite;
```

I guess that it solves your problem.

Comment: The animation does work. I just don't know how to make it `animate` on hiding again. At the moment it only 1 way animates.

Comment: Also, using `opacity` instead of display made the animation that original was working, not work anymore.